# How to simply draw an image to a window in windows OS with c++

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering, gdi+

I am trying to learn the basics of graphical programming (IN GENERAL, not specifically windows), and would like to use the simplest, most encapsulated methods. I have the following code and would simply like to draw an image to the screen.

Note: The game->update is a call to my own class meant as the main game. I want to handle everything pertaining to my game there. That is why it is in the game loop.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Asteroid_Game.h"


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY) { PostQuitMessage(0); return 0; }
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPWSTR cmd, int nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
ZeroMemory(&windowClass, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
windowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
windowClass.lpszClassName = "MainWindow";
windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

RegisterClassEx(&windowClass);

RECT rect = { 0, 0, 1000, 1000 };
AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false, WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);

HWND windowHandle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, "MainWindow", "Asteroids - Pre-Alpha 0.1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100,
    rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance, 0);

if (!windowHandle)return -1;

ShowWindow(windowHandle, nCmdShow);

MSG message;
message.message = WM_NULL;

Asteroids* game = new Asteroids();

while (message.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    else
    {
        // Game Loop:
        game->update();
}

delete game;

return 0;
}
```

I want to draw an image, say with the name "image.png". 
I need to know the syntax. 
Remember, I want to stay as encapsulated as possible. In other words, the less Windows API, the better.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It sounds like you want to get into some lower-level calls.  As you've already noticed, even probing a couple of layers lower in Windows still places an opaque layer over their internal trickery.  Looking at something like http://www.xfree86.org/ as a starting point as to how GUIs are built might be helpful.  The question as it stands would take book chapter or much more to answer ( I did not downvote, but that was probably the reason someone did).

Comment: You are not handling `WM_PAINT` in windows procedure, so nothing will be painted. I don't what `game->update()` does, but it's probably wrong. You should start with a more basic introduction to WinAPI programming.

Comment: I assumed as much. I only began looking into WINAPI and I am already sick of it's over complication. I will research WM_Paint and see from there. No worries about the down vote, the community here is often harsh on non-general questions.